# NX: can't execute storybook

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl, angular-storybook

we cannot install storybook into a NX project (latest version), works only in the version 11.1.5 but it doesn't start , below the steps to reproduce it:

```
> rm -rf node_modules      
> npm i
> nx migrate 11.1.5
> npm i @nrwl/storybook -D     

> manually update versions
 "@nrwl/angular": "11.1.5",
 "@nrwl/cli": "11.1.5",
 "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "11.1.5",
 "@nrwl/jest": "11.1.5",
 "@nrwl/linter": "11.1.5",
 "@nrwl/storybook": "12.0.8",
 "@nrwl/tao": "11.1.5",
 "@nrwl/workspace": "11.1.5",

> npm install

> npx nx g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration frontend-core

> npx nx run frontend-core:storybook
```

after execute the last command **storybook doesn't start and it doesn't show any errors**

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Which version of Nx are you migrating from? Also, I see that your version of `@nrwl/storybook` is inconsistent with the version of the rest of the `@nrwl/*` packages. I think that if you align the versions of the packages it should work. You can try `npm i @nrwl/storybook@11.1.5 -D` and then see what's going on.

Comment: hey! which options are you chosing for your storybook configuration? (are you choosing to create stories for every component?)